how to import a file from a package that requires another package within its own folder to run
revitalize/
├── app.py
├── static/
├── templates/
├── GFPGAN/
│   ├── experiments/
│   ├── gfpgan/
│   ├── inputs/
│   ├── results/
│   └── inference_gfpgan.py
└── DeOldify/
    ├── deoldify/
    ├── fastai/
    ├── fid/
    ├── test_images/
    ├── result_images/
    └── image_colorizer.py

this is the folder tree structure,Here from the app.py, I'm trying to import image_colorizer from DeOldify, but image_colorizer requires deolodify, fastai within DeOldify package to run. so this leads to raise the import error while running the flask app.
app.py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory,redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

from DeOldify import imageColorizer


 
app = Flask(__name__)

reconstruct = True

loc1 = 'inputs\whole_imgs'
loc2 = 'DeOldify\\test_images'

upload = loc1 if reconstruct else loc2

app.config['UPLOAD'] = upload
 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file_upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD'], filename))
        return redirect('/reconstruct')
    return render_template('index.html')
 



@app.route('/colorize', methods=['GET','POST'])
def colorize():
    imageColorizer.ColorIMG()
    return render_template("index.html")

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=4339)

image_colorizer.py
from deoldify import device
from deoldify.device_id import DeviceId

from deoldify.visualize import *

def ColorIMG():
    # setting-up GPU
    device.set(device=DeviceId.GPU0)
.
.
.

I was expecting it to use the ColorIMG() from deoldify without spitting any import error.
I tried importing the deoldify from app.py but no luck, I looked up online for hours and I couldn't find any relevant solution for this problem. I appreciate any help to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

To import a module that are in same directory of another module you have to use the dot notation for relative imports.
from .deoldify import something
from .deoldify.some import thing

Note that you cannot make a relative import in a main script, cause it is running as a top-level (the Python file you ran to start things off).
# app.py
from .DeOldify import imageColorizer

It will generate a ImportError.
In image_colorizer.py you can do something like that:
# image_colorizer.py
from ..GFPGAN import inference_gfpgan

But in that case it will not work cause GFPGAN is in same directory of app.py, which is running as top-level. And the dot notation cannot reach the top-level/root directory.
Note:

Make sure create a __init__.py file for every directory that you will use as a package and/or if have a python file in there to be used as a module.
